# Find differences in strings on pandas column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have the following pandas DataFrame from [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1d29v_mFvc6CupeRcHJtnHzTEX81P_2WX/view?usp=sharing) CSV file

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv('Last_year.csv')
df.groupby('School Status').size().plot(kind='pie', autopct='%1.1f%%')
```

I would like to know how I can remove the error which is causing me to have 3 divisions and not 2 as programmed

Here is the result
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have more spaces in one of the labels.

To check what are the labels that pandas detects, you can use [`Series.unique()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unique.html#pandas.Series.unique).

You can remove whitespace from beginning and end for example by using [`str.strip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) element-wise, doing:

```
import pandas as pd  # This code is from OP
df=pd.read_csv('Last_year.csv')  # This code is from OP
df['School Status'] = df['School Status'].map(str.strip)
df.groupby('School Status').size().plot(kind='pie', autopct='%1.1f%%')  # This code is from OP
# Now you can plot your DF
```

Comment: better `f['School Status'] = df['School Status'].str.strip()`

Comment: @ssice is there a way to apply this method to all the other columns?

Comment: Yes. You have [`DataFrame.applymap()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html#pandas.DataFrame.applymap) if you want it for the whole DataFrame, or for a subset: `df[['A', 'B']] = df[['A', 'B']].applymap(str.strip)`

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you're having these three dimensions in your DataFrame.

`df['School Status'].unique()`

`array(['IN SCHOOL', 'OUT OF SCHOOL', 'OUT OF SCHOOL '], dtype=object)`

So, if you'll remove whitespace after the last one, it should work properly:

Try this snippet:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv('Last_year.csv')
df['School Status'] = df['School Status'].replace({'OUT OF SCHOOL ': 'OUT OF SCHOOL'})
df.groupby('School Status').size().plot(kind='pie', autopct='%1.1f%%')
```